# create nuget package fails with 'Path is not of a legal form'

Tags: c#, msbuild, nuget

In a post build step we create nuget packages. For some reasons this always fails on my machine, while it works on other developers machines.

The command executed is:

```
nuget.exe  pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Properties Configuration=$(ConfigurationName) -OutputDir "$(ProjectDir)..\Apps"
```

The output i get is:

```
Packing files from ''.
Using 'Organisation.AppName.Modules.Kcs.nuspec' for metadata.
The path is not of a legal form.
```

For other developers the first line contains the directory. What can be the reason it is working differently on my box? Are there options i can set to change this behavior?

**Edit:**
I downloaded the nuget source and found the point things start to go wrong. With a small test program i can simulate it:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Build.Evaluation;

namespace CheckTarget
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (args.Length == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("usage: CheckTarget projectfile.csproj");
                Console.WriteLine();
                return;
             }

             string path = args[0];
             var project = new Project(path);


             Console.WriteLine("TargetDir = {0}", project.GetProperty("TargetDir") != null ? project.GetProperty("TargetDir").EvaluatedValue : string.Empty);
             Console.WriteLine("TargetPath = {0}", project.GetProperty("TargetPath").EvaluatedValue);
             Console.ReadKey();
         }
     }
}
```

On my machine the targetdir is null, on another machine the targetdir points to valid directory.

Comment: What are the actual underlying paths of the VS variables, then?

Comment: The values shown under Edit post-build command line > Macros are: TargetPath = C:\RootDev\2.6\Organisation\AppName\KcsModule\bin\debug\KcsModule.dll

Comment: have either of your ProjectPath or ProjectDir got spaces in them? If so that'd explain why it works for your collegues - you want to quote the arguments then

Comment: No, none of the paths and directories containts spaces. One of my collegues does have spaces in the projectDir and it works on his machine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally found the answer. This thread helped me locate the problem:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/msbuild/thread/d3c6e2de-1e87-49c2-b059-df074868e315/

On my machine there was an environment variable 'platform' with value 'BWS'. Deleted it and things are working!

Comment: Did you just set the variable to an empty value or did you delete it in registry?

Comment: As far as i can remember: i just deleted it in the registry

Answer (score 4):

Use property Platform to -Properties parameter in nuget program

```
-Properties Platform=$(Platform)
```

where $(Platform) is one of your project platform (defined in csproj file, typically x86, 'Any CPU', ..).

ie in your case, run something like:

```
nuget.exe pack "$(ProjectPath)" -Properties Configuration="$(ConfigurationName)" Platform="$(Platform)" -OutputDir "$(ProjectDir)..\Apps"
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem basically **it was an old nuget version that I carried in my source control**, I deleted the .nuget folder then I uninstalled nuget from visual studio, by selecting

> tools > extensions & updates,

select nuget & uninstall and then do the same process but for Installing it, just make sure you al searching in the "online" repository.

Answer (score 0):

I had to update the Nuget Manager from Updates And Extensions. Restarted VS, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was that no .dll was inside the `Debug` folder and without the `-properties Configuration=Release` option nuget usually tries to find a dll in the `Debug` folder.

Running `nuget pack` manually gave me an useful error message. Running it as post build event I got the same obscure error message as you.